# How to cancel a once() call before answer?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So what's the proper way of canceling a `.once()` call before the database has answered?

I have a use case where if the database takes more than a few seconds to answer, I don't want the answer. I'm using a promise notation, but if required, I could switch to the callback notation.

Promise notation:

```
firebase.database().ref('something').once('value').then(...)
```

Callback notation:

```
firebase.database().ref('something').once('value',snapshot => {...})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unregister listeners by calling `off()`.

See the [reference documentation for `off()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#off). It only speaks of working for `on()`, but it will work for `once()` listeners too.

I'm not sure what it would accomplish though, as the `value` listener will fire right away anyway.

Comment: The time it takes to answer really depends on the connection and the amount of data, no?